# Template specialisation or function overload

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, initializer-list

I created a two classes - one can be converted to another by the conversion operator:

```cpp
struct MyClass{};

struct MyClass2{
    operator MyClass() const { return MyClass{}; }
};
```

and a specialised template function (specialisation for `std::initializer_list<MyClass>`):

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(std::initializer_list<T>)
{
}

template<>
void foo(std::initializer_list<MyClass>)
{
    std::cout << "specialised template foo<>()";
}
```

When I try to call `foo` with the initializer list mixing `MyClass` and `MyClass2`:

```cpp
foo({MyClass{}, MyClass2{}, MyClass2{}});
```

compiler opposes (as I am mixing two different types):

```
<source>:35:8: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   35 |     foo({MyClass{}, MyClass2{}, MyClass2{}});
      |     ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:19:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T> void foo(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)'
   19 | void foo(std::initializer_list<T>)
      |      ^~~
<source>:19:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:35:8: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_Tp' ('MyClass' and 'MyClass2')
   35 |     foo({MyClass{}, MyClass2{}, MyClass2{}});
      |     ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But from some reason if I add an non-template overload of `foo` for the same type as in template specialisation - it works like a charm!

```cpp
void foo(std::initializer_list<MyClass>)
{
    std::cout << “overloaded foo()";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    foo({MyClass{}, MyClass2{}, MyClass2{}}); // Program stdout : overloaded foo()
}
```

I guess that non-template overload has a priority over templates when compiler looks up for a function. But why it does work with overload and does not work with template specialisation? Is it undefined behaviour? Or is it completely legal to do it so?

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/5ohhK1jeb

Comment: Do not use initializer list as function arguments (they are kind of broken).  But use `template<size_t N> foo(const type_t (&values)[N])`.

Comment: In the non-template overload case the overload is unambigously a better fit and the type is known to be `MyClass` and no deduction is needed. In the specialization case the type `T` needs to be deduced to determine whether a specialization should be used or not.

Comment: It is template deduction that fails. The compiler cannot find a `T` that matches the parameter types. When you have a non-template, there is no deduction and the compiler goes directly to type conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it does work with overload and does not work with template specialisation?

- specialization doesn't participe to overload selection, only the primary template does. (After primary template is selected, specialization are "used" for definition).
- template deduction "ignores" type conversions.
- `{..}` has no types, and can only be deduced in few context. As its types are not all the same, `{..}` cannot be deduced as `std::initializer_list<T>`.

With overload `void foo(std::initializer_list<MyClass>)`, no deduction occur, and might check if we can match argument to this function, and the provided `{MyClass{}, MyClass2{}, MyClass2{}}` can indeed be an `std::initializer_list<MyClass>`

That's why overload should be preferred over specialization in general case.

> Is it undefined behaviour? Or is it completely legal to do it so?

There are no undefined behavior.
overload is completly legal.